# How can I reshape list of numpy arrays? I want to reshape it like this-> (num_samples, img_size, img_size, num_channels)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

**Edited**:**I am providing data loading code as well**
How can I reshape it for my network. So far, I used this way of reshaping and it was fine for me but now It's not working( *I dont know why*.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import model

import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, GlobalAvgPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

textdir = r'F:\LOCAL_DATASETS\CNR-EXT-Patches-150x150\LABELS'
datadir = r'F:\LOCAL_DATASETS\CNR-EXT-Patches-150x150\PATCHES'
train_test_val = ['train.txt', 'test.txt', 'val.txt']


def imgToArray(text = 'train', img_shape = 150):
    data = []
    x_data = []
    y_label = []
    if text == 'train':
        with open(os.path.join(textdir, 'train.txt')) as e:
            for line in tqdm(e):
                path = os.path.join(datadir, line.split(' ')[0])
                class_num = int(line.split(' ')[1])
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_shape, img_shape))
                    data.append([img_array, class_num])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

    elif text == 'test':
        with open(os.path.join(textdir, 'test.txt')) as e:
            for line in tqdm(e):
                path = os.path.join(datadir, line.split(' ')[0])
                class_num = int(line.split(' ')[1])
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_shape, img_shape))
                    data.append([img_array, class_num])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

    elif text == 'val':
        with open(os.path.join(textdir, 'val.txt')) as e:
            for line in tqdm(e):
                path = os.path.join(datadir, line.split(' ')[0])
                class_num = int(line.split(' ')[1])
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_shape, img_shape))
                    data.append([img_array, class_num])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
    else:
        print("File not found!")

    random.shuffle(data)
    for features, label in data:
        x_data.append(features)
        y_label.append(label)

    return np.array(x_data), np.array(y_label)

x, y = imgToArray('train')
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
x_data = x.reshape(-1, 150, 150, 3) <- problem is here!
```

**And I got the following error**. Maybe I missed some updates from numpy or I made a mistake:

```
ValueError:Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-4b9ee0985e72> in <module> ----> 1 x_data = x_data.reshape(-1, 150, 150, 3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 94493 into shape (150,150,3)
```

1. **How can I get my data samples look like this: (9493,150,150,3)**

Comment: Please add the code to the question as code formatted text and not as an image. It makes it easier for people wanting to help.

Comment: If it used to work, what has changed? New data? Have you checked the shape and dtype of the data before the reshape attempt?  If it used to work, then you **do** know how to reshape.

Comment: Does the (94493,) shape make sense?  Anything like what you expected?  Did you look at an element of it?

Comment: @hpaulj, yes I checked. When I check for each sample, the dim is `(150,150,3)`. However , When I check it for my bunch of data the dim is `(94493,)`

Comment: If `x.dtype` is `object`, then this is an array of arrays.  Most likely one or more of those arrays is not (150,150,3).

Comment: `x.dtype` is `numpy.ndarray`. I did the same thing with https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/